# How does rsync behave with --append and --link-dest together?

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync

The question refers to the case where a file exists both in the origin and the link-dest folder, but it's larger in the origin. Will it hard-link it and append inplace (thus modifying the file in link-dest)? Or will it copy locally and then append?

If it's not the case already, is there any way to get it to copy the file locally and append only the extra while still having untouched files hard linked?

Comment: testing it locally appears to produce a very strange behavior: link-dest file is not modified and the new file in the destination contains only the new content (all hard link counts are 1)